# problemas con la configuracion de GitLab, netbeans y linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, ubuntu, git

cuando utilizo git por consola a la hora de hace un push o pull tira el error
fatal: unable to access 'https://pagina del proyecto: Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT.
Pude lograr hacerlo funcionar mediante la interfaz git de netbeans pero, si quiero ejecutarlo desde la consola de linux(ubuntu) o la terminal de netbeans. tira ese error. El proxy esta configurado creo que el problema viene que cuando pide la credencial de GitLab no la tiene. Por la interfaz de Netbeans te deja configurarle una, no se como ver que credecial de git esta usando o como cambiarla.

Comment: has un git remote -v para ver a que repositorio apunta

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes unas claves exportadas en git deberias cargarlas antes de hacer pull o push con un agente, tal y como yo lo hago es siguiendo la siguiente secuencia:

```
export https_proxy="https://tuproxy:puerto"
# El siguiente comando mata cualquier sesion de ssh-agent y levanta una nueva con la clave que se le pasa
kill -USR1 pgrep $(pgrep ^ssh-agent);eval "$(ssh-agent -s)";ssh-add ~/.ssh/tuclaveprivada
```

Ahora podrias hacer un git pull pero asegurandote como ha comentado Igmer que la configuracion de git es la correcta con git remote -v:

```
# git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/tuusuario/tugit.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/tuusuario/tugit.git (push)
```